Comparing the Lie bracket of vector fields with the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ for Riemannian homogeneous spaces
Consider a Riemannian submersion $(G, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_G) \xrightarrow{\pi} (H, \langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_H)$, where $G$ is a connected Lie group, $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_G$ is a left-invariant Riemannian metric, and $H \cong G/K$ for some closed Lie subgroup $K$ of $G$. Denote the Lie algebras of $G$ and $K$ by $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$ respectively. Then there exists a complementary subspace $\mathfrak{h}$ such that $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$. Moreover, since a Riemannian Homogeneous space is reductive, and $G$ is connected, we have the following inclusions:
$$ [\mathfrak{k}, \mathfrak{k}] \subset \mathfrak{s}, \qquad [\mathfrak{k}, \mathfrak{h}]\subset \mathfrak{h}$$
Since left-translation is an isometry, we can obtain similar decompositions along all tangent spaces of $G$, from which the horizontal and vertical bundles can be constructed.
On the other hand, in The Fundamental Equations of a Submersion by Barrett O'Neill (1966), the concept of basic vector fields is introduced, which are precisely the horizontal lifts of vector fields on $H$ to $G$. Here, it is stated that if $X$ is a basic vector field and $V$ is a vertical vector field, then $\pi_{\ast}[V, X] = [\pi_{\ast}V, \pi_{\ast} X] = 0$, so that $[V, X]$ is vertical. In particular, $[V, X](e) \in \mathfrak{s}$.
However, I would expect from $[\mathfrak{k}, \mathfrak{h}] \subset \mathfrak{h}$ that $[V, X]$ is horizontal, since clearly $V(e) \in \mathfrak{k}$ and $X(e) \in \mathfrak{h}$. An issue here, of course, is that we are talking about different Lie brackets in the two cases: one is the Lie bracket of vector fields, and the other is the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$, which are related only through left-invariant vector fields. I would suppose then that there can be no left-invariant basic vector fields (aside from the trivial vector field) if both are to remain true.
Is there any sort of satisfactory explanation as to why the distinct notions of Lie brackets on $G$ seem to behave so fundamentally different with respect to the decomposition of the tangent bundle into the vertical and horizontal subbundles?
